I don't understand what しようと決めました means in the sentence 彼は初めてタイ料理にしようと決めました
It seems that タイ料理にしよう is the volitional form of タイ料理にする, which means "decide to make the Tai food", and と決めました also means "decide to do something". So the sentence means "He decides to make Thai food for the first time?" If so, why does it use the volitional form, and why does it repeat "decide" twice (first being にする, and second being と決める)? Or maybe I missed something?

Although Aにする and Aに決める are sufficient in many cases, Aにすると決める is also a valid and common combination in Japanese.
Aにする means "to go with A" or "to choose A", and it doesn't necessarily carry the nuance of serious decision making. にする is used when there are two or more options. 決める on the other hand is explicitly about decision making, like "to decide on A" or "to make up one's mind".
While "I decided to choose A" may sound a little redundant in English, Aにすると決める sounds natural in Japanese.
